# Filter list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to **filter list of tuples** with two conditions if `tuple value is greater than 0.3` and `there should not be more than 5 elements picked if first condition satisfies` but not able to fit both.

List of tuples:

```
list_of_tuple = [(254, 0.9637927264127298),
 (354, 0.8522503527571762),
 (32, 0.7816368211562529),
 (165, 0.7545730507118511),
 (65, 0.730523154567809),
 (223, 0.6863456501573775),
 (263, 0.6630003543540749),
 (357, 0.6322069100774286),
 (383, 0.6134476413586814),
 (252, 0.5608248345843365),
 (31, 0.5123749051906423),
 (347, 0.466326739057893),
 (486, 0.3487919085343739),
 (54, 0.29397783822097),
 (257, 0.23987209993003836),
 (92, 0.22892930134708775),
 (7, 0.20977065219601607),
 (166, 0.19997039737766586),
 (145, 0.15806269571615644),
 (463, 0.1455164252456856),
 (139, 0.14485058856127903),
 (302, 0.14029875929667127),
 (320, 0.12460879531407618),
 (141, 0.12100147679918186),
 (350, 0.12007000240833345)]
```

Expected Result: (As there are more than 5 values here if first condition `(>=0.3)` satisfies), So get top 5 only

```
a = [(254, 0.9637927264127298),
 (354, 0.8522503527571762),
 (32, 0.7816368211562529),
 (165, 0.7545730507118511),
 (65, 0.730523154567809)]
```

I tried

```
a = [item  for item in list_of_tuple if (item[1]>=0.3) and len(list_of_tuple)<=5]
```

but it returns an empty list.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: returns empty list

Comment: Do:  `[i for i in list_of_tuple if i[1] >= 0.3][:5]`  You want to filter the individual items according to the `>= 0.3` criteria, and *then* take the first 5 out of those results.

Comment: don't want to slice afterwards...want to include as condition

Comment: Your first example didn't work because `len(list_of_tuple)<=5` is false.

Comment: Can you show an example where `[i for i in list_of_tuple if i[1] >= 0.3][:5]` would give a wrong result?

Comment: I didn't say it will give wrong result...i don't want to slice after i get the result

Comment: @martian_rover you can't when you are doing the list comprehension *because the list doesn't exist yet*. You could come up with some hacky way, but just use an explicit loop and check the length of your result.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes that is what i was exactly looking for...thanks

Comment: So, along the lines of what you tried, you can:

```result = []
    [result.append(item) for item in list_of_tuple if item[1]>=0.3 and len(result) <=4]
    print(result)```
Note that 4 will give you a desired length of 5.

Comment: @Ketan, this will still process through the full list of tuples. OP wants to stop processing once the count hits 5.

Comment: @JoeFerndz, True and I didn't find this requirement in question. Thanks for mentioning though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
result = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] >= 0.3, list_of_tuple))[:5]
print(x)
```

Note that this isn't optimal if your list is very long, since the entire list is generated.

This is better for really large lists:

```
from itertools import islice

result = list(islice(filter(lambda x: x[1] >= 0.3, list_of_tuple), 5))
print(result)
```

Comment: I think this is what i was looking...thanks

Comment: Or perhaps `list(islice(( item  for item in list_of_tuple if (item[1]>=0.3) ), 5))`

Comment: Does't the `islice` process `filter(lambda x: x[1] >= 0.3, list_of_tuple` first and get the full list, then stop at the 5th one?. Or does it send `filter(lambda x: x[1] >= 0.3, list_of_tuple` to do its job 5 times?

Comment: Filter constructs and returns an iterator and `islice` only gets the first 5 elements from that iterator, so no more logic is executed than is required to get the first 5 values. So it doesn't send filter to do its job 5 times per se, but it avoids comparing all the tuples and only executing the comparison for the first 5 tuples.

Answer (score 1):

`itertools` is handy for this sort of stuff:

```
from itertools import islice

a = list(islice((item for item in list_of_tuple if item[1] >= 0.3), 5))
print(a)
# [(254, 0.9637927264127298), (354, 0.8522503527571762), (32, 0.7816368211562529), (165, 0.7545730507118511), (65, 0.730523154567809)]
```

`islice` with a generator expression won't evaluate more of the list than necessary.